# Need Help in Client and Server Programming in C

Tags: c

I am coding a small C program to test the client and server programs so that the client sends an integer to the client. The server multiplies the number by 10 and returns the integer*10 back to the client. When writing the integers to the FIFO, use sizeof(int) as the number of bytes in the 3rd parameter of the write( ) and read( ).
That is my code so far:
The Client task:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main (void)
{
  int fda;  // to write to server
  int fdb;  // to read response from server

  int number;
  int outputnumber; 



 if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_WRONLY))<0)
          printf("cant open fifo to write");

 if((fdb=open("FIFO_to_client", O_RDONLY))<0)
         printf("cant open fifo to read");

 printf("Client: Please enter an integer: ");
 scanf("%d", &number);


  write(fda, &number, sizeof(number));
  printf("\nClient: Got the number sent, now waiting for response ");
  read(fdb, &outputnumber, sizeof(outp utnumber));
  printf("\nClient: received from server %s", outputnumber);

  close(fda);
  close(fdb);

  printf ("\nall done!\n");

  }
```

The server task:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

main (void)
{
  int fda;  // to read from client
  int fdb;  // to write to client
  int finish;   // lets me know that client is done

  int number;
  int outputnumber;



  /* Create the fifos and open them  */
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO_to_server",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
  {
    perror("cant create FIFO_to_server");
    exit(-1);
   }

  if ((mkfifo("FIFO_to_client",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
  {
    perror("cant create FIFO_to_client");
    exit(-1);
   }

  if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_RDONLY))<0)
      printf("cant open fifo to write");

  if((fdb=open("FIFO_to_client", O_WRONLY))<0)
      printf("cant open fifo to read");

  finish=read(fda, number, sizeof(number));     //read the character

  printf("Server: just got the number: ,%d", number));

  outputnumber = 10*number;

  write(fdb, outputnumber,sizeof(outputnumber)); 
  printf("\nServer: Got the number sent");

  if(finish == 1)
      printf("\nServer: This says I am ready to close ");

  close(fda);
  close(fdb);
  unlink("FIFO_to_server");
  unlink("FIFO_to_client");

}
```

The Client's output show error:

```
-bash-3.2$ ./client
Client: Please enter an integer: 10

Client: Got the number sent, now waiting for response
Client: received from server ▒+▒▒▒▒▒▒7▒▒x}

all done!
```

The Server:

```
-bash-3.2$ ./server
 Server: just got the number: 134614968
 Server: Got the number sent-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Try doing this for starters: Change: `printf("\nClient: received from server %s", outputnumber);` to: `printf("\nClient: received from server %d", outputnumber);`

Comment: Also please turn on compiler warnings like I mentioned in your previous question, and you'd see this issue.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks :)